# How rewrite a URI in nginx?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Please consider the following directory structure in my root:

```
/resources/css
/resources/js
/resources/templates
/resources/images
```

I want to serve static content from the above directories but
I also want to allow a rewrite like this to work:

```
rewrite ^/([a-z]+)(.*)$    /index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2;
```

For example `myurl.com/register/...` is rewritten to `myurl.com/index.php?p1=register&p2=...`

But that rule also rewrites `/resources/`, so how do I exclude `/resources` from the rewrite? Or do I need another rewrite? Nothing I've tried seems to work so obviously I'm not understanding something.

Comment: Can you please fix the typo in your `rewrite` above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The config below is what I found that works, since the location statements are
all the same precedence they are checked in order.

This helped me understand the precedence of location blocks:

```
location =  <path>  (longest match wins)
location ^~ <path>  (longest match wins)
location ~  <path>  (first defined match wins)
location    <path>  (longest match wins)
```

Here is the config:

```
// match all css/js/images in resource path

location ~ ^/resources {
        root   /mypath/myurl.com;
        try_files $uri =404;
        break;
}

// allow myurl.com/register etc:

location ~  ^/([a-z]+)/(.*)$ {
        root   /mypath/myurl.com;
        rewrite ^/([a-z]+)(.*)$    /index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2;
}

// everything else:

location ~ / {
    root   /mypath/myurl.com;
    index  index.php;
}
```

Comments welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ MSIE) {
  rewrite  ^(.*)$  /msie/$1  break;
}

if ($http_cookie ~* "id=([^;] +)(?:;|$)" ) {
  set  $id  $1;
}

if ($request_method = POST ) {
  return 405;
}

if ($slow) {
  limit_rate  10k;
}

if ($invalid_referer) {
  return   403;
}

if ($args ~ post=140){
  rewrite ^ http://example.com/ permanent;
}
```

For more information, visit: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule

Answer (score 0):

You could just add another location handler for that URI that matches on files that exist - or breaks if they don't.

```
location ~* /resources/(css|js|templates|images) {
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
  root   /path/to/resources;
}

rewrite ^/([a-z]+)(.*)$    /index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2;
```

Comment: That looks reasoanable to me but does not seem to work, it's still trying to rewrite the resources directory.

Comment: Its the right code. So the next question is whether the file you are trying to access is readable by the web-server - and that you have entered your Nginx config in the right order as above. Paste your full Nginx config to confirm.

Comment: The files were accessible and the code was copy/pasted from above and edited properly. I found after researching that using (if) is not recommended by nginx, please see: [nginx docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil), so I did not try using this code further. Thanks for your input!

Comment: `if` is fine as long as you aren't using it to conditionally set variables; you are safe to use `break` in an `if` without any issue. This is the right method, short of using `try_files`. Post your full Nginx config - as at the moment, the code is out of context and your placement of it is probably the cause.

Comment: I posted the working solution that does not use *if*.